# Como puedo evitar que se sobrescriban los datos en openCV python

Tags: python, opencv

estoy realizando un proyecto de tracking con openCV y python en sus ultimas versiones. Pero al momento de cuando ingresa un 2do o tercer objeto a la pantalla, los datos se solapan y generan inconsistencias de datos. ¿ Como puedo evitar esto ?

https://youtu.be/OU1Kwz3pbGA Video explicativo del problema
https://pastebin.com/0ETYfZw2 Codificación

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se solapan? en el video veo que los cuadros nunca se solapan.

Comment: La pregunta debe contener todo la información necesaria sobre el problema, sin necesidad de salir de este sitio. En particular el código debe estar aqui; no todo el código; solo una versión mínima que demuestre el problema. Mira [mre]

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa , las identificaciones de los objetos cambian, es decir, cuando reconoce un objeto, a ese se le asigna "Objeto 1" pero cuando aparece un segundo objeto, el primer objeto queda como "Objeto 2" y el segundo como "objeto 1" eso, me provoca inconsistencia de datos